# What does this joke mean here?

Tags: jokes

> These two old boys hung their peckers off a bridge to piss.
> One was from California, one from Arkansas. Old boy from California says,
> "Boy, this water's cold." Old boy from Arkansas says, "Yeah, and it's deep too."

What does this joke mean?

Comment: Hi Ken,  Where did you read this joke?  What is the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an old joke. The "old boys" are bragging about the size of their penises

"The water's cold" implies "my penis is long enough to water in the river below".

"It's deep too" implies "my penis is long enough to reach the bottom of the river."

If this is from the film I think it's from, you're going to have a hard time if you try to understand everything. There is a lot of Arkansas "good ol' boy" dialect. You'll enjoy it better if you just accept that you'll only get the gist.  In this case the gist is "It is a dirty joke".  But if you really want an analysis: Someone has actually written a thesis: [Gendered sense of humor as expressed through aesthetic typiﬁcations](https://www.academia.edu/3418394/Gendered_sense_of_humor_as_expressed_through_aesthetic_typifications)

Comment: That joke is told world wide only with different nationalities or places of origin for the two men.

Comment: I have seen the joke told about soldiers of different rank, e.g. the private has the short penis and the old sergeant the long one. In general, the long penis belongs to some group favoured by the joke teller.

Comment: Yes.  Though I do think this guy tells it wrong.  It should be "Californian: It's cold. Arkansasan: Yes, and deep!"  With the first guy meaning "weather is cold" and the second misunderstanding so you get a double-meaning. But this joke is as old as the Ozarks.  The linked paper really goes to work deconstructing the humour in the movie.